# id to title url rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to convert id to title in url address bar , i found many question related this topic .i also created .htaccess file in root directory code look like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   RewriteEngine On     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ProductDetail.php?Product=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`
```

But nothing work .i am new in rewrite URL, i just want to convert
    `ProductDetail.php?Product=1212` To `ProductDetail/Title`
Thanks for your kind regards

Comment: You need to take care that that dynamic configuration file you created is actually considered by the http server. Take a lolok at the `AllowOverride` feature in the documentation of apaches rewriting modules.

Comment: AllowOverride All  But Not Work

Comment: Have a try to check that: place a definite syntax error in that configuration file. Do you get an error in your http servers error log file afterwards? Which error?

Comment: Oh, obviously you also need to make sure that the rewriting module is actually loaded into the http server.

Comment: And what folder do you actually refer to with the term "root directory"?

Comment: i have xampp  and in folder i have my website project ,i created this .htaccess in project folder

Comment: And the other questions I asked?

Comment: I do not think you can achieve this with htaccess alone. The easy way would be to add some code to ProductDetail.php to detect if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is ProductDetail.php?something and if so, do a header('Location: '.getNiceAddress($product), true, 301);

The .htaccess code you posted is doing the opposite - it's sending the nice urls as parameters to ProductDetail.php

Answer (score 1):

One basic rule for url rewriting is that *it is not possible to process the query while rewriting it*

If in your example `ProductDetail/Title` Title means the title of the item having the `product=1212` we need to actually run the query to find the `Title` before even generating the url, which in turn will lead to change in the query method of your website and thus making it less efficient (Instead of using the `product` in the where clause you have to use a string which will replace the `Title`).

We can however create the transformation from `ProductDetail.php?Product=1212` to `ProductDetail/1212` with the following code

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./ProductDetail.php?Product=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Also, you need to precede the php file with a `./` in your path as php file resides within a directory. Otherwise it might generate an error or it won't work at all.

Regards